# "Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." - but domain is the same (css)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, express

I'm getting an error trying to load a css file in JavaScript: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://complice.co/m/user.css?3239. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

...but the domain I'm loading it from is the same! Why is it showing up as Origin: `null`? I'm just using a basic AngularJS `$http.get(url)` to fetch it.

Also I'm pretty sure this has worked before, and I haven't changed anything. I also wouldn't be surprised if it just worked again next time. But what I'm wondering is ***how is it even possible for this error to occur?***

[image: devtools screenshot]

Comment: One thing I'm noticing as I poke at this is that I'm not fetching /m/user.css?3239, but that I'm sending the full url (https://complice.co/m/user.css?3239) to the get request. I'm guessing that if I change that, it'll fix this, but I still don't understand why!

Comment: Did you get this error online ?

Comment: most probably it is called from iframe, and there are limitations for iframe. Also we do not know origin of that iframe, etc...

Comment: @AllanRaquin: as in "while connected to the internet?" Yes. The request itself was triggered by a socket message, so necessarily so.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov thanks for the suggestion but there's no iframes on that page.